# How to use arguments like $1 $2 ... in a for loop?

Tags: bash, shell-script, arguments

I have this script which designed to download the pronounciation of the words you give it as argument:

```bash
#!/bin/bash 
m=$#
for ((i=1;i<=m;i++));do

echo $i
#wget https://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/de/0/"$i".mp3
done
```

if I run it by this command

```
./a.sh personality brave selfish
```

it should print on the stdout

```
personality 
brave 
selfish
```

but instead it prints

```
1
2
3
```

would you help me solve this problem?

p.s : If I write the script without for loop with $1 for example it will work correctly but I want to download many files at the same time

Comment: Unfortunately bribing a for loop will cost you at lot more than $1 or $2, you need to be prepared to pay around $2,500-3,000 ;)

Comment: you can use `$1` and `shift` on all the args. I have seen it done, not sure it is a good idea, unless you need several of the arguments in the same iteration of the loop, I guess. I'll try to find an example of use tomorrow.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In any Bourne-like shell, it's:

```
for arg
do printf 'Something with "%s"\n' "$arg"
done
```

That is, `for` does loop on the positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`...) by default (if you don't give a `in ...` part).

Note that that's more portable than:

```
for arg; do
  printf 'Something with "%s"\n' "$arg"
done
```

Which was not POSIX until the 2016 edition  of the standard nor Bourne (though works in most other Bourne-like shells including `bash` even in POSIX mode)

Or than:

```
for arg in "$@"; do
  printf 'Something with "%s"\n' "$arg"
done
```

Which is POSIX but doesn't work properly in the Bourne shell or ksh88 when `$IFS` doesn't contain the space character, or with some versions of the Bourne shell when there's no argument, or with some shells (including some versions of `bash`) when there's no argument and the `-u` option is enabled.

Or than

```
for arg do
  printf 'Something with "%s"\n' "$arg"
done
```

which is POSIX and Bourne but doesn't work in very old ash-based shells. I personally ignore that and use that syntax myself as I find it's the most legible and don't expect any of the code I write will ever end up interpreted by such an arcane shell.

More info at:

- http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/bourne_args/
- [What is the purpose of the “do” keyword in Bash for loops?](/a/306944)

---

Now if you do want `$i` to loop over `[1..$#]` and access the corresponding elements, you can do:

in any POSIX shell:

```
i=1
for arg do
  printf '%s\n' "Arg $i: $arg"
  i=$((i + 1))
done
```

or:

```
i=1
while [ "$i" -le "$#" ]; do
  eval "arg=\${$i}"
  printf '%s\n' "Arg $i: $arg"
  i=$((i + 1))
done
```

Or with `bash`

```
for ((i = 1; i <= $#; i++ )); do
  printf '%s\n' "Arg $i: ${!i}"
done
```

`${!i}` being an indirect variable expansion, that is expand to the content of the parameter whose name is stored in the `i` variable, similar to `zsh`'s `P` parameter expansion flag:

```
for ((i = 1; i <= $#; i++ )); do
  printf '%s\n' "Arg $i: ${(P)i}"
done
```

Though in `zsh`, you can also access positional parameters via the `$argv` array (like in `csh`):

```
for ((i = 1; i <= $#; i++ )); do
  printf '%s\n' "Arg $i: $argv[i]"
done
```

Comment: Interesting that you do not mention (from the mascheck page you link to) `zsh until release 4.3.0, in sh emulation mode (which means the option shwordsplit is set), does word splitting on the resulting arguments.` and that the only version of bash (the only shell you specifically mention by name) that needs a very corner case addition is `bash-4.0.0 ... -4.0.27`. May we call that `a little biased report`?

Comment: @sorontar, I mention bash because that's the shell mentioned by the OP. For `zsh` in sh emulation there used to be a problem with `${1+"$@"}`, not `"$@"` alone.

Comment: Exactly my point: there is a (somewhat corner case) issue also with zsh.

Comment: About `for arg do` (without the `;`), the same mascheck page says: `The original Almquist shell (ash) accepts all but the second variant.`. Thus, the only really portable solution is `for arg <newline> do`.

Comment: @sorontar, the zsh issue you mention is not relevant to this Q&A, it's about the `${1+"$@"}` construct which is not needed to loop over the positional parameters. My whole answer does say that `for arg <newline> do` is the most portable. I'm not sure I understand the point you're trying to make.

Comment: I'm... not really sure that calling bash more Bourne-like than POSIX-like is fair. bash doesn't try to be Bourne-compatible -- witness `echo hello ^ cat` not treating `^` as a pipe -- whereas excluding `echo`, it tries to implement a superset of the POSIX sh specification (and even `echo` can be strictly compliant, when built with `--enable-xpg-echo` or given appropriate runtime configuration).

Comment: Maybe it's also worth mentioning that with `-c` flag in bourne-style shells , the `$0` gets assigned the first argument value instead of the shell/interpreter name. This is mentioned in the `man` page for `bash` and has been tested with `mksh`, and `ksh`. The typical trick is to use a dummy argument. For instance, `bash -c 'for i;do echo "$i"; done' sh  one two three`. And just a small addition - same trick with different shells: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23272236/

Comment: @Charles, I never said `bash` was or intended to be Bourne compatible. It is a Bourne-like shell in the loose sense like ksh, yash or zsh. It can't be Bourne-compatible as it aims to be POSIX compliant (at least in some environment as you say). AFAIK, it's the only open-source shell that has been POSIX and Unix certified (in OS/X at least)

Comment: What are you talking about? The whole and unique purpose of [the mascheck page](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/bourne_args/) is to describe the need, use and consequences of using the `${1+"$@"}` construct. It is equally relevant to any shell named there. If it is relevant to bash, it is equally relevant to zsh. What it say about bash is: `At least these shells need that workaround` (the use of the `${1+"$@"}` construct.  What it say about zsh is: `${1+"$@"} is reliable and portable -- with one exception:  zsh until release 4.3.0 …` (the failure to accept the `${1+"$@"}` construct).

Comment: @sorontar, exactly, the mascheck page is about `"$@"`, this Q&A is about looping over the positional parameters for which the syntax is `for i do`. I only mention `for i in "$@"` because that was the solution proposed by another answer (now deleted). `"$@"` would still be relevant to some other Q&A like _how to loop over the position parameters *and something else*?_ or _How to pass the positional parameters as-is to a command_, in which case the answer might want to point out the `${1+"$@"}` WA for the bugs in those old shells, and then mention the different behaviour of old zsh in sh emulat

Comment: @sorontar, Note that zsh in sh emulation doesn't pretend to be Bourne or POSIX compatible (just like in csh emulation it doesn't pretend to be csh compatible), though it tries as much as possible. Strictly speaking `${1+"$@"}` being subject to work splitting in those old versions was not a bug, but down to how zsh nested parameter expansions in this instance (other shells don't support nesting expansions consistently like zsh does). (continued)

Comment: Changing it meant breaking backward compatibility (and a fundamental change) which explains why it was delayed for so long even though the compatibility issue with sh was known from the start. Now `${=foo+"$bar"}` doesn't split `$bar` like it did before (though `${(s: :)foo+"$bar"}` still does)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, is `for arg in "$@"; do ...` not POSIX compliant? I prefer it because it is the most explicit way to loop through the arguments.

Comment: @Harold, yes it's POSIX (I've updated the answer) but not the most portable.

Comment: I'd prefer ${!i}.

Answer (score 4):

I would use `shift`. This one `[ -n "$1" ]` means while arg-1 is non-empty, keep looping.

```
#! /bin/bash 
while [ -n "$1" ]; do
  echo "$1"
  wget "https://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/de/0/$1.mp3"
  shift
done
```

Comment: What if the script is called as `my-script foo '' bar`? It would be better to use `while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]` (or ksh/bash/zsh-specific `while (($# > 0))`)

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way

```
#!/bin/bash
for i
do
 echo $i
done
```

and run

```
./a.sh personality brave selfish
```

and here is the print on the stdout

```
personality
brave
selfish
```

Comment: Does this add anything to the prior answer, which AFAICT includes this idiom? `echo $i` is buggy, by the way -- if you have an argument passed as `"*"`, you would instead have a list of filenames in the current directory emitted; should be `echo "$i"`.

Comment: ...and `printf '%s\n' "$i"` *is* actually more correct than `echo "$i"` -- if your argument is `-n`, `printf` will print it, but `echo` may not ([the POSIX specification for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html) defines behavior as entirely undefined if the first argument is `-n`, or if *any* argument contains a backslash literal; moreover, some popular `echo` implementations defy black-letter POSIX by having `-e` or `-E` arguments have a behavior other than printing like strings on output).

Comment: The script does nothing. Pls explain!

Comment: @hschou, if it "does nothing", then you aren't passing it any arguments.

Comment: @hschou, I have updated the answer. The answer explains everything.