# How to prevent `ls` from sorting the output?

Tags: ls, sort

I have a specific order of files that I want to list if they exist; around 40 files. Some kind of precedence. So I tried:

```
ls -1d         /opt/foo/lib.jar /opt/bar/lib.jar
```

I expected this to list `/opt/foo/lib.jar` first if both exist.
But actually it prints the `bar` first and the `foo` after that.

Is there some way to make `ls` list the entries in the order given in parameters?
Or some alternative approach with `find`?

Comment: Did you mean to say (for internal consistency) that you expect foo to be listed fit?

Comment: How would you describe the rule for sorting these 40 files? Completely manually based on the command line?

Comment: This question has been negatived from someone, I don't think this was fair.  This is a legitimate question and, indeed, Mathew's answer seems to address it correctly.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes, on a command line. It's a script that's identifying what's "installed". I admit there could be a smater way (a list in a file) but the way to get the script and files to the machine is complicated, so this works best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After mentioning `find`, I found out that it can take more than 1 path as the path argument. So it is simply:

```
 find /opt/foo/lib.jar /opt/bar/lib.jar -prune 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but not the correct answer to the question. See @Matthew answer below.

Answer (score 14):

With GNU `ls`, you could try the `-U` option:

> `-U`:     do not sort; list entries in directory order

(though here, we're not listing the content of directories, so the part that matters is *do not sort*).

```
$ ls -1dU /opt/foo/lib.jar /opt/bar/lib.jar
/opt/foo/lib.jar
/opt/bar/lib.jar
```

Slightly more portable (works with GNU and FreeBSD `ls`, but not with traditional `ls` implementations and is not POSIX either), you can use `ls -1df`:

```
$ ls -1df /opt/foo/lib.jar /opt/bar/lib.jar
/opt/foo/lib.jar
/opt/bar/lib.jar
```

Comment: I should suggest you to complete your answer based on his own command.

Comment: Mac's `ls` [does not support `-U`](https://ss64.com/osx/ls.html). So, while this is better for Linux, for a general case I opted for `find` as I need this to work on MacOS, too.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a wrapper function around `ls` that loops over the arguments (in the order they're given), calling `ls` on each:

```
myls() {
  for arg do
    ls -d -- "$arg"
  done
}
```

With a reference to Stéphane's answer in [How to use arguments like $1 $2 ... in a for loop?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/314032/117549) for the `for arg do` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In `zsh`, to reduce a list of files to the ones that exist, you can use the `(N)` glob qualifier appended to each element of the list:

```
files=(/opt/foo/lib.jar /opt/bar/lib.jar)
that_exist=($^files(N))

(($#that_exist > 0 )) && print -rl -- $that_exist
```

Note that contrary to `ls`, it can tell whether a file exists or not even if you don't have *search* access to its parent directory (as long as you still have read access), as it looks for corresponding entries in the directory without trying to access the file.

See also:

```
that_exist_after_symlink_resolution=($^files(N-^@))
```

Which selects the files that are not (`^`) a symlink (`@`) after symlink resolution (`-`). Equivalent to using `ls -Ld`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of pathnames that you'd like to go through and test for existence, then I presume that you'd like to either do something fol the ones that do exist, for the ones that don't exist, or for both sets of pathnames.

Given a standard shell, this is best done in a loop.

```
for pathname in /the/first/path /the/second/path /some/other/path
do
    if [ -e "$pathname" ]; then
        printf 'Path "%s" exists\n' "$pathname"
    else
        printf 'Path "%s" does not exist\n' "$pathname"
    fi
done
```